# Refactoring not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In the ASP.Net 4.5 Gridview Databound event below, which works perfectly fine as is, it appears to me that the "If Not usr Is Nothing Then"  code line should actually be outside the For EAch DataControlField loop since I only need to check that once. However, when I wrap the whole logic with that  "If Not usr Is Nothing Then" ( see the second code iteration), I get an error. Any thoughts

```
 Protected Sub gvEBEvals_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvEBEvals.DataBound

    Dim revColumn As Integer = -1
    Dim currentColumn As Integer = -1
    Dim usr As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    For Each col As DataControlField In gvEBEvals.Columns
        If Not usr Is Nothing Then
            If (Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "administrator") Or Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "developer")) Then
                If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "revenue potential" Then
                    revColumn = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                    For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.rows
                        If revColumn > -1 Then
                            row.Cells(revColumn).Text = String.Format("{0:c0}", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(revColumn).Text))
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "is current" Then
            currentColumn = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
            For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.Rows
                If currentColumn <> -1 Then
                    If row.Cells(currentColumn).Text = "True" Then row.Font.Bold = True
                End If

            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Revised code using one call to test the  existence of the user user, which errors

```
If Not usr Is Nothing Then
        For Each col As DataControlField In gvEBEvals.Columns              
                If (Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "administrator") Or Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "developer")) Then
                    If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "revenue potential" Then
                        revColumn = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                        For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.rows
                            If revColumn > -1 Then
                                row.Cells(revColumn).Text = String.Format("{0:c0}", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(revColumn).Text))
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "is current" Then
                currentColumn = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.Rows
                    If currentColumn <> -1 Then
                        If row.Cells(currentColumn).Text = "True" Then row.Font.Bold = True
                    End If

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
   For Each col As DataControlField In gvEBEvals.Columns
        If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "is current" Then
            currentColumn = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
            For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.Rows
                If currentColumn <> -1 Then
                    If row.Cells(currentColumn).Text = "True" Then row.Font.Bold = True
                End If

            Next
        End If
 Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no responses, I made several different refactors and the following code works as expected.

```
 Protected Sub gvEBEvals_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvEBEvals.DataBound

    Dim usr As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    If Not usr Is Nothing Then
        For Each col As DataControlField In gvEBEvals.Columns
            If (Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "administrator") Or Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "developer")) Then
                If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "revenue potential" Then
                    Dim revColumn As Integer = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                    FormatCurrencyColumn(sender, revColumn)
                End If
            End If

            If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "is current" Then
                Dim currentColumn As Integer = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                BoldTrueRows(sender, currentColumn)
            End If
        Next
    Else

        For Each col As DataControlField In gvEBEvals.Columns
            If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "is current" Then
                Dim currentColumn As Integer = gvEBEvals.Columns.IndexOf(col)
                BoldTrueRows(sender, currentColumn)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub FormatCurrencyColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal revColumn As Integer)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.rows
        If revColumn > -1 Then
            row.Cells(revColumn).Text = String.Format("{0:c0}", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(revColumn).Text))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BoldTrueRows(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal currentColumn As Integer)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.Rows
        If currentColumn <> -1 Then
            If row.Cells(currentColumn).Text = "True" Then row.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```